# Custom Bean Validator -- JSR303/JSR349 can Validator choose message when invalid?

Tags: bean-validation

Is there a way to let a validator specify the message when the validation fails?  I know I can implement the annotation so I can use it like this (would probably use enums instead of strings for `value`, in practice):

```
@Check(value="Type1", message="{type1.checkFailed}") public MyClass myVal1;
@Check(value="Type2", message="{type2.checkFailed}") public MyClass myVal2;
```

And that will get the end result I want.  I can also implement multiple annotations/validators and do it this way and specify a default message in the definition of the annotation:

```
@CheckType1 public MyClass myVal1; // default message is type1.checkFailed
@CheckType2 public MyClass myVal2; // default message is type2.checkFailed
```

What I'd like to do is let the validator associated with `@Check` determine whether to use `type1.checkFailed` or `type2.checkFailed` as the message, depending on `value`, like this:

```
@Check("Type1") public MyClass myVal1;
@Check("Type2") public MyClass myVal2;
```

It is my understanding that the best practice is to keep a validator focused on a single characteristic.  But I don't think what I'm trying to do is contrary to this since it is validation for a single characteristic, there are just variants of it that can be validated.

As an example using dog breeds:

```
@BreedSize("Large") Dog bigDog;
@BreedSize("Small") Dog smallDog;
```

Since a given annotation can only appear once on an element (at least as of SE7), this might also be a reasonable way to ensure only one of several mutually-exclusive validations take place. I think there was/is a proposal for multiple annotations of the same type on an element, but I suppose the validator could check that only one was supplied, in that case -- getting ahead of things here, though.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom constraint violation object via `ConstraintValidatorContext` passed to the `isValid()` method like this:

```
public class BreedSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BreedSize, Dog> {

    private String value;

    @Override
    public void initialize(BreedSize constraintAnnotation) {
        this.value = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(
        Dog object,
        ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {

        if ( object == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean isValid = ...;

        if ( !isValid ) {
            String messageKey = "Large".equals( value ) ? 
                "{BreedSize.Large.message}" : "{BreedSize.Small.message}";

            constraintContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            constraintContext
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( messageKey )
                .addConstraintViolation();
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```